# Should a g_object_new have a matching g_object_unref?

Tags: c, memory, glib, gobject

I'm using *libnotify* to show desktop notifications in my [application](http://artha.sourceforge.net/); [`notify_notification_new()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libnotify/unstable/NotifyNotification.html#notify-notification-new)  returns a `NotifyNotification*`, which should be passed as the first param to further function calls of the notification library.

There is no `notify_notification_free()` which frees the pointer it returns. I looked up the source of `notify_notification_new()` and internally it does a `g_object_new()`, gets a **GObject*** and returns it as a `NotfiyNotification*`, so when my application does the clean up, should I call a `g_object_unref()` on the pointer returned by `notify_notification_new()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, unless the reference is "floating". Subclasses of `GInitiallyUnowned` use floating references; the most common use is GTK widgets.

When you create a GTK widget using a `gtk_whatever_new()` function, it has one reference which is marked as floating. When you add the widget to a container, the container must also hold a reference to the widget. But instead of calling `g_object_ref()` on the widget and increasing the reference count to 2, it "sinks" the object's floating reference and turns it into a normal reference. You could say that the container now "owns" the widget.

Then when you destroy the container, it calls `g_object_unref()` on the widget, and the reference count becomes zero, and the widget is destroyed. That way you're not responsible for destroying it yourself anymore.

So with normal `GObject`s, which usually don't go into containers, there is no transfer of ownership. You have to unreference them yourself when you're done with them.

Comment: @ptomato what additional headers do I need to call `g_object_unref()`? I'm currently including only `libnotify/notify.h`.

Comment: `#include <gobject/gobject.h>`

Comment: @ptomato, why do they use `g_object_unref(model)` on a GTreeModel [here](http://scentric.net/tutorial/ch-treeview.html). Is it a bug in their code then?

Comment: They *are* adding the `model` into a `GtkTreeView`. Or is it the fact that `GtkTreeView` isn't a `GtkContainer` why they must call `g_object_unref`?

Comment: `GtkTreeModel` isn't a subclass of `GInitiallyUnowned` (see the first paragraph above) so it doesn't have floating references.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, I figured it out from [Gnome's page on ownership](http://live.gnome.org/Vala/Ownership#Ownership_in_GLib), I hope it helps someone later.